# Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column Text_from_Customer must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0

Tags: r

Does anybody know why am I getting this error here? If yes, How can I resolve this issue?

This code is working fine on my sample dataset but if I apply this on my whole dataset, I'm getting the above error.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(bindrcpp)

df2<-read.csv("filepath.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

df2 %>%
    mutate(Body_text = sub("^.*Agent\\s\\w+", "", Body_text)) %>%
    separate_rows(Body_text, sep="\\s(?=\\w+:)") %>% 
    separate(Body_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s?") %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Id, newgrp = str_c('Text_from_', 
        replace(Text_from, Text_from != "Customer", "Agent"))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = newgrp, values_from = value) %>%
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarise(AgentName = first(Text_from),
              Text_from_Agent = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Agent), collapse=' '),
              Text_from_Customer = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Customer), collapse = ' '))
```

The following image is my sample dataset.

[image: dataset sample]

Can anyone fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In the `summarise`, try  `Text_From_Agent = if(all(is.na(Text_from_Agent))) NA_character_ else str_c(Text_from_Agent[!is.na(Text_from_Agent)]), collapse=' ')` and similary for 'Customer'

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much!  But a small closing bracket typo error I guess from you. The line should be Text_From_Agent = if(all(is.na(Text_from_Agent))) NA_character_ else str_c(Text_from_Agent[!is.na(Text_from_Agent)], collapse=' ')                           
                                                                                                                            
 Can you explain what the above line does?

Comment: I added some description in solution

Comment: Oh ok. Also is there a way to remove agent names and customer names from the formatted text or before formatting?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, `group_by(Id) %>% filter(any(!is.na(Text_from_Agent)))`

Comment: does the above line remove agent name from the entire Body_text at this step?

Comment: yes, it would remove the 'agent_name' for those cases where there is NA

Comment: Ok, what about cases that are not NA. When customer is chatting with the agent, they often address the agent name when speaking, right? I basically want to remove  agent name from Text_from_Customer column.

Comment: In that case you may need to remove with `sub` or `str_remove` to remove that substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make a condition to check if all the  elements columns for a particular group are `NA`, then return `NA` or else `paste` the non-NA elements in `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
    mutate(Body_text = sub("^.*Agent\\s\\w+", "", Body_text)) %>%
    separate_rows(Body_text, sep="\\s(?=\\w+:)") %>% 
    separate(Body_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s?") %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Id, newgrp = str_c('Text_from_', 
        replace(Text_from, Text_from != "Customer", "Agent"))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = newgrp, values_from = value) %>%
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarise(AgentName = first(Text_from),
              Text_from_Agent =  = if(all(is.na(Text_from_Agent))) NA_character_ else str_c(Text_from_Agent[!is.na(Text_from_Agent)]), collapse=' '),
              Text_from_Customer = if(all(is.na( Text_from_Customer))) NA_character_ else str_c( Text_from_Customer[!is.na( Text_from_Customer)]), collapse=' '))
```